# Multi domain Magento Store Issue - Experts reviews

Tags: magento

I have Followed eveything from the link below 
https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=30&useful=vote

and also from magentocommerce.com's tutorial to set up multi domain store.

I have two different domains store1.com and store2.com

where,I have installed magento in store1.com followed the instructions properly from various tutorials .

After configurations are done, store2.com doesn't seems to  load at all.

But also no sites (Tutorial) mentions what to do in second domains cpanel? i.e store2.com panel that is having its different login and server.

As it is completely blank and i really dont understand what to do with that second domain's account.

how second domain would be knowing the magento is trying to glue with it.

Some1 Expert on this pls help

Thanks.

Comment: does both the configured domains share the same document root?

Comment: i have configure in a manner below.
i have domain 1 with cpanel where i have parked the second domain. ie
store2.com
but it also seems not to be working.
and about the first domain i think we dont have to do anything to that .

Comment: As I observe the steps mentioned in the above mentioned URL has all the ingredients to setup a multi-site setup successfully, especially pay attention to 'Domain Mapping' section of the article, if you are using an Apache server.

Comment: thanks for the response,
i am not able to map the domain ,i think thats the place where i am getting stucked :(

Comment: Get help from the support of your hosting team to get those details added